# Transporting player from different places via touching a block

Tags: lua, roblox

I need help transporting player from different places via touching a block. As in to teleport player to another PLACE, not location, within the experience. Whats meant to happen is the player to touch a part and then to be teleported to a place.

```
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")
local Part = script.Parent
local TARGET_PLACE_ID = 12108199305 -- replace with your own place ID

local playerToTeleport = Players:GetPlayers()[1] -- get the first user in the experience


local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer

Part.Touched:Connect(function(Object)
    if Object.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        
        TeleportService:TeleportAsync(TARGET_PLACE_ID, game.Players[Object.Parent.Name])
    end
end)
```

I get this error: `17:20:06.603  Unable to cast value to Objects  -  Server - Script:15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```lua
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")
local Part = script.Parent
local TARGET_PLACE_ID = 12108199305 -- replace with your own place ID


local Players = game:GetService("Players")


Part.Touched:Connect(function(Object)
    if Object and Object.Parent then
        local PlayerName = Object.Parent.Name
        if Object.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and Players:FindFirstChild(PlayerName) then
            TeleportService:TeleportAsync(TARGET_PLACE_ID, Players[PlayerName])
        end
    end
end)
```

Note: Put the code in server sided script in the part instead of a local script!

Let me know if it works!